# Using Mask in processing.js

Tags: processing, mask, processing.js

I'm pretty new with *Processing.js* and I was wondering why this simple mask is not working? I mean, I can display the image and the mask without any problem, but as soon as it reach the line `img1.mask(mask1);` everything stop working.

```java
/* @pjs preload="resources/images/1.jpg, resources/images/masks/1.jpg"; */
void draw(){  
    PImage img1 = loadImage("resources/images/1.jpg");
    PImage mask1 = loadImage("resources/images/masks/1.jpg");
    img1.mask(mask1);
    image(img1, 0, 0);
}
```

I have read http://processingjs.org/reference/PImage_mask_/, but I don't see what i'm doing wrong :S
Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try it outside of the `draw()` method? That's the only suspicious looking thing to me.

Comment: No, I use it inside the draw(). If you want, you can see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/GhSTE/ it won't work since it doesn't have access to the images from there, but it will give you an idea. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code from jsfiddle and it's working with Processing.js 1.3.6.
Note that you have to run it from a web server, opening the html file from the filesystem will give you the blank canvas in Chrome or just the text in Firefox.

<sub>If you don't have an access to a web server you can install one on your own computer ([XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is good and multiplatform, I personally use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) on Windows)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The code is actually working great, but only in *Processing*, not in *Processing.js* even though this fonctionnality appear in both reference pages http://processingjs.org/reference/PImage/